# flutter app problem with display zoom option in ios

Tags: ios, flutter, settings, display, flutter-getx

in flutter app when ios users change the display zoom option in iphone setting my flutter widgets be in wrong design i can prevent when user change the text size by using
this code inside GetMaterialapp
*MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
textScaleFactor: 1.0, devicePixelRatio: 1.0, size: Get.size),*
but this code didnt work with display zoom option

i want way or some lines in info.plist to add it to prevent or override the display zoom option

Comment: Having the same problem, any conclusions?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Is there a solution to this?